# Docker Environment variable not working in CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i'm trying to pass the name of the script from the docker run but its not getting the script name in the cmd command.

Not sure what's wrong here, same thing works fine in springboot/java projects

[image]

[image]

Below is the docker file

```
FROM python:3.8.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs  

RUN apt-get install -y npm 

WORKDIR  /rubix-kyc

COPY . /rubix-kyc

RUN pip install -r  /rubix-kyc/requirements.txt

ARG SCRIPT_NAME

ENV SCRIPT_NAME ${SCRIPT_NAME}

RUN mkdir -p video_recording/

RUN npm install

RUN npm install elastic-apm-node --save

EXPOSE 4443

CMD [ "npm", "run" , "${SCRIPT_NAME}"]
```

Updating the script for running docker.

```
docker run  \
-e SCRIPT_NAME=start-local \
-p 4443:4443 $1
```

Need you help here

Comment: Are you sure you're building your image with the `build-arg` set, e.g.: `docker build --build-arg SCRIPT_NAME=example_script`

Comment: Please post also your ```docker run``` command.

Comment: @m19v updated the script , please check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the variables used in `CMD` it is important to pass it as environment variable on `docker run` besides defining with `ARG` and assigning with `ENV` in Dockerfile, as it is evaluated on runtime, e.g.:

```bash
docker run --rm -ti -e SCRIPT_NAME=value-of-script-name <docker-image-id>
```

Please adjust your Dockerfile as well:

```
ARG SCRIPT_NAME
ENV SCRIPT_NAME=$SCRIPT_NAME
...
CMD npm run $SCRIPT_NAME
```

Comment: i'm passing the argument in docker run command, Please check the script . I have updated in the question

Comment: Check the answer, i have adjusted it. I.e. adjust the line with ENV in Dockerfile as ```ENV SCRIPT_NAME=$SCRIPT_NAME```

Comment: and CMD in Dockerfile

Comment: thank you so much it worked, haven't used --rm and -ti till date,
Need to read more about that